# Java Convert Negtive Binary String to Decimal

Tags: java

`Integer.parseInt(str, 2)` used to convert binary string to a decimal num.
But for negative num of binary string, the binary string must be the complement prefixed with `-`.
Is there any present method to do the convert?
Thanks.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    byte[] bs = {-128,1,2,0};
    String bsBits = "10000000000000010000001000000000";//bit representation of bs
    String bsBitsComplement = "-1111111111111101111111000000000";//complement of bsBits
    int v = 0;//bs converted to a int value
    for (int i = 0; i < bs.length; i++) {
        v = (v << 8) | Byte.toUnsignedInt(bs[i]);
    }
    System.out.println(v);
    String sv = Integer.toBinaryString(v);
    System.out.println(sv);
    System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(bsBitsComplement, 2));//success
    System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(bsBits, 2));//error
}
```

This is the output when I run the above code:

```
-2147417600
10000000000000010000001000000000
-2147417600
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "10000000000000010000001000000000" under radix 2
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:67)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:668)
    at baseproj/basetest.Main.main(Main.java:39)
```

Comment: "But for negetive num of binary string, the binary string must be the complement prefixed with `-`" How else would you like a negative number to be represented? 32-bit two's complement?

Comment: It is currently not clear what you are asking. Can you add an example of what (values) you tried and what result you expected?

Comment: question updated, thank you all

Answer (score 0):

I assume, the input is array byte[4]. So I propose this method:

```
public static String getHumanComplementAsString(byte[] bs) {
    int v = 0;//bs converted to a int value
    for (byte b : bs) {
        v = (v << 8) | Byte.toUnsignedInt(b);
    }
    return ((bs[0] < 0) ? "-" : "") + Integer.toBinaryString(Math.abs(v));
}
```

Don't have time to test it completely with positive values and zero. Leaving it to you :)
Hint. Your definition of complementary for negative integer corresponds to "Human" Binary representation option in [online tool](https://onlinebinarytools.com/encode-negative-binary) You can use this page for comparison with the program's result.

Comment: Thanks, it is my fault and what i want to ask is if there is any present method to convert binary string to int no matter it is negtive or positive.

Comment: Since Java 17 you can use HexFormat
HexFormat format = HexFormat.of(); String hex = format.formatHex(bs); byte[] output = format.parseHex(hex);